# Insert "-" in the name of all files in a folder at position 4 and 6

Tags: windows, vbscript, rename

I got a bunch of PDFs in a folder which must be renamed. They are all built like this: `YYYYMMDD_Text.pdf`. The system is Windows 7.

I want to insert a `-` between the dates, so the documents look like:
`YYYY-MM-DD_Text.pdf`.

This is what I got, but it's not working and I searched a dozen threads but could not find the solution:

```
    Ordner = "C:\xte Stelle\Test Doku"

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Fld = fso.GetFolder(Ordner)

    For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
        WScript.Echo i & vbTab & Arr(i)
    Next

    For Each File In Folder.Files
        File.Name = Left(File.Name, 4) & "-" & Mid(File.Name, 6) & "-" & Mid(File.Name, 8)
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

This is what I got now. I can run it and it does not crash, but does not function either. It simply does nothing. Any idea on that?

```
Ordner = "C:\xte Stelle\Test Doku"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Fld = fso.GetFolder(Ordner)

Sub test
    For Each File In Fld.Files
        File.Name = Left(File.Name, 4) & "-" & Mid(File.Name, 5, 2) & "-" & Mid(File.Name, 7)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: As already mentioned: you need to actually invoke the procedure. Add a line `test` at the end of the script.

Comment: I am a little bit confused, but that worked! Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not only incomplete, but downright broken.

- You have an `End Sub` without a corresponding `Sub`.
- You assign a folder object to the variable `Fld`, but then enumerate files from a variable `Folder`.
- Your second `For Each` loop is missing a `Next`.
- The [`Mid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wffts6k3) function returns the number of characters defined by the third parameter starting from the position defined by the second parameter. If the third parameter is omitted the substring from the position defined by the third parameter to the end of the string will be returned. Hence your filename reconstruction should look like this:

  ```
  File.Name = Left(File.Name, 4) & "-" & Mid(File.Name, 5, 2) & "-" & Mid(File.Name, 7)
  ```

---

**Note:** if you put your code in a procedure or function you need to actually invoke that procedure/function to get the code executed.

Comment: Ordner = "C:\xte Stelle\Test Doku"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Fld = fso.GetFolder(Ordner)

For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
    WScript.Echo i & vbTab & Arr(i)
Next
For Each File In Fld.Files
File.Name = Left(File.Name, 4) & "-" & Mid(File.Name, 5, 2) & "-" & Mid(File.Name, 7)
 next    First: Sorry, I have no idea how to format this block, if I press return it justs sends the whole block as as comment.. Second: Thank you very much! I adapted the code, but its still not working. Could you please help my finding a solution?

Comment: @Spike87 Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44900125/1630171) if you need to provide additional information. Also include information about how *exactly* your code is "still not working". We're not sitting in front of your computer, so you need to describe the behaviour you see. Since you seem to have wrapped your code in a procedure: are you actually calling that procedure?